# get data form webservice by sendAsynchronousRequest.

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, asynchronous

```
+ (NSData *) sendGETRequest:(NSString *) url
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:10];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) 
        {
        [Common alertStatus:@"N/A PTZ" :@"System error!"];
        }];
}
```

I want to get data from web services and I have used `sendAsynchronousRequest` but It does not run! Maybe I have done something wrong. Please help !!

Comment: I don't know whether I got it right or not but try with [NSOperationQueue mainQueue].

Answer (score 0):

When using async, you should just call start on the NSURLConnection object and deal with callbacks in the delegate. 
Otherwise, use sendSynchronousRequest: